# I'm facing an error in my Tkinter app. The Entry widget is only giving me the value "0"

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code:

```py
income_benefit = Entry(ret_calc, font="Arial", background="#CAE7DF", textvariable=i)
income_benefit.pack()
mai = int(maturity_entry.get())
print(mai)
```

It's showing the value of var 'mai' is zero, although I'm giving natural numbers as input. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're calling `.get()` on the Entry immediately after creating it.  There hasn't been any time for you to type in any input yet.  You need to do the `.get()` *later* - typically in a Button's `command=` function.

Comment: What is `i` in `textvariable=i`?  Also `maturity_entry` is not defined in your code. It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Also, what is `maturity_entry`? You don't show how that is created. Please create a [mcve] and add it to your question. Is this code run after the user has had a chance to enter data, or before?